# Understanding audio jack connections

Tags: plug, connecting

I have an audio jack but I have no clue how to connect wires to it. Please help me to understand its connections. I have provided the images of it. I do not know how to connect it, please help.

[image]

It has three pins at the back end (long, medium, and short in length.)

SPEAKER, to which I want to connect
[image]

Comment: Just measure continuity with a multimeter, is what I'd do.

Comment: the plug consists of three concentric tubes ... the middle one is the tip

Comment: To what you want to connect it? Are you asking which terminal is which contact on the connector, or what are the functions of the contacts/terminals for your application? Is it a headphone, microphone, line in/out, MIDI, something else?

Comment: I want to connect it to a speaker; the input will be from a mobile device and output will be from the speaker

Comment: @Preet To which kind of speaker, like directly to an actual speaker element with impedance of e.g. 8 ohms, or some other kind of device like an active speaker with line input and amplifier? Which connector there is on the other end?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a mobile device is intended to be connected to headphones, not directly to speakers.

Speakers have lower impedance (e.g. 8 or 4 ohms) than headphones (32 ohms typically, but phones allow down to 16 ohms).

So if you connect your phone to a speaker directly, please be aware that it may not work like you expect, the quality may be poor or there could be damage.

Having said that, the TRS connector tip (shortest solder terminal) is the left speaker output, ring (middle length solder terminal) is the right speaker output and the sleeve (longest solder terminal) is the ground.

Use either left or right output, preferably left, and ground, and connect them to speaker positive and negative terminals.

Comment: I am actually making an audio mixer so I have to use a series of OpAmp, resistances and capacitor between the phone and speaker. So will it still damage the speaker? I have already simulated it on MultiSim and it is working perfectly. But do I still have to worry regarding the damage to the speaker?

Comment: @Preet You said you wanted to connect it to a speaker. And you are not, you want to connect it to an opamp. Oh well. Same connections still apply to connector even if you connect to an opamp. It's not the speaker I am worried about, but damage to your phone.

Comment: So, can you suggest some ways to avoid damaging my phone?

Answer (score 2):

The connection are as follows with colored lines pointing at the area:

[image]

Blue is the sleeve or ground, red is the ring, and green is the tip. Hearth's comment is correct for double checking yourself.